# Mentor .........?

Tags: prepositions

I want to tell someone he is my mentor

1. He is my mentor for xyz
2. He is my mentor of xyz
3. He is my mentor at xyz

Which is correct 
Pls let me know

Thanks

Comment: The correct answer could be 1 or 3, depending on whether xyz is a field of endeavor, a place. an institution, or perhaps something else.  I can't think of an example in which 2 would be correct, but that may be attributable to my lack of imagination rather than its being truly incorrect.  In any event, it's not possible to answer this question definitively without having more information about the nature of xyz.

Comment: Hello @Sudheera. Your question is actually about the preposition: you might like to take a look at [our help on preposition questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info) which tells you how they work and what sort of information is needed to answer questions reliably. If the existing answer doesn't actually help, you can always [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/526328/edit) your question to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition should be based on what type of mentorship or which aspect you wish to highlight. As such: for a field of study, "in" may be appropriate; a goal or personal/professional development target, or specific timespan would fit with "for"; "at" emphasizes the location (employer, institution, etc) over the subject of mentoring.

I might suggest eliminating the preposition altogether, also:

`They are my xyz mentor.`

Comment: This works for "He is my college mentor" and "He is my football mentor" etc.

Answer (score 1):

He is my mentor at the community college.

He is my mentor in mathematics.

He is my mentor from 10 to 12 this morning.